# Create .apk file data to be stored in data/data/package_name/files folder

Tags: android

From my application I am downloading a few files and storing it in data/data/package_name/files folder and I'm accessing and viewing those files and I download that file once and each time I run application.

I could view that file as the data is persistent in data/data/package_name/files folder so it is not lost when session ends.

All this I am doing in the emulator. Now I have created an .apk file of my application and installed it on a real device. I am expecting that the "data/data/package_name/files" is also packed up with it but which is not happening. I can't see the downloaded file.

As my problem is that I could not connect to Internet from my real device, I could not download file. Is there any way that I could create an .apk file along with the data in "data/data/package_name/files"?

Answer (score 1):

save these files in assests folder, instead of saving in your app memory space, it will not go with your apk.below link will help you in the same [storing file in assets which will go with apk](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/assets.html)

Comment: No,i have to create it in the same application memory.No other option to save the files any where else as i have also given provision from my application to delete the downloaded files if required.

Comment: yes the memory area which i meantioned(assets) is also your app memory area, difference is that the files downloaded or added in this folder will go with your apk file

Comment: so can i create different folders in (asset folder)??? and from my application i could delete the perticular folder stored in asset folder.is it possible?? and I have to store huge amount of data so is it convinient to save in asset folder.I thought that application would crash so i droped idea to save files in asset...

Comment: i do not know if you can or can not create folder on under assets, but yes you can push data of certain limits. check out the link I provided you to know more about assets, and also read from developer site. but if you want to achieve your requirement you need to change store area which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want copy that file to your device during testing. You can upload the file from PC to mobile device by DDMS tool.

Choose the DDMS View from Eclipse, then click the icon of 'Push a file onto the device' on the tab of 'File Explorer',then select the file from the open dialog. That's all.

Comment: Push file onto device is used to save ur file from pc to emulator. And my Issue is very different I want to create .apk file along with the files in data/data/package_name/myfolder/..